# KDE Startup Applications over xrdp

Tags: kde, startup, vnc

I have Google Chrome installed on my machine. The new chrome runs in the background (for addons like google chat) and has an entry in the KDE startup apps. The trouble I am facing is that when I log in to an xrdp session, a chrome window starts up on the local session along with more vino-server session.

How do I fix this? How do I stop chrome from opening a new window at the local session?

I am using Mint 13 on x64